# Scrapy Json format for geolocation is always reverted

Tags: json, mongodb, scrapy

I'm setting my Geolocation object as follow :

```
markers['coordinates']={ "lng":item['longitude'],"lat":item['latitude']}
```

But when inserted, it goes like this

```
 coordinates: { lat: 31.7754 , lng: -98.9915 }
```

I'm sure it's the same line , because I set lat to 0 and it was inserted 0 
Ladies and gentelmen, I'm going crazy.

Comment: Python `dicts` don't guarantee key order. Why do you need a specific order?

Comment: Because in MongoDB, I set a spherical index, and it should have the format of Longitude / latitude.
Elsewhere, I get an error message
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: insertDocument :: caused by :: 16755 Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?

Comment: You probably have an invalid format of the GeoJSON object - check the format for the point here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#geojson-point

Comment: No, the type attribute is for Spherical indexes Version 2 (introduced in MongoDB Version 2.6) , I have specified when creating the index that the index is version 1

Comment: The problem is in the dict order, I need to preserve the order : Longitude / Latitude , the dict gets reverted, for whatever reason it is.. (Maybe sorting keys in alphabetical order..)

Answer (score 0):

Solution  : Ordered Dicts:

```
...
import collections
...     
markers['coordinates']=collections.OrderedDict()
                    markers['coordinates']['lng']=item['longitude']
                    markers['coordinates']['lat']=item['latitude']
```